# How to make two changes on GitHub go into two separate PRs?

Tags: git, github

I saw an open source project on GitHub, and want to made some changes to it.

(Update: and I did it all on the GitHub website, because I needed to use a different account but haven't set up two accounts in Bash on my machine).

So I forked the project, and then made some changes to one file, and then created the PR to the original repo.

It is all fine as I see the PR in the PR list of that repo.

But right now I want to make another change to a different file.  So I made the change, and committed, and wanted to create another PR.

The reason is, even if they approve the first PR, they may not approve the second PR, or vice versa, so it is better to keep the two PRs separate.

However, I saw that it automatically went into the first PR, and there was no way in the process to let me make it into a separate PR.

How can it be done?  I did it all on GitHub because I haven't set up two different github users on my local machine using Bash. In the past I was able to just do it on GitHub as a different user and create two separate PRs as I recall, but not any more.

Comment: When you say you did it all "on GitHub", what do you mean exactly? Did you use tools on your machine such as the `git` CLI or an IDE, or did you do everything from the `github.com` web site without ever cloning the repo to your local machine?

Comment: right, I did all things on the GitHub website.  I needed to use a different account than my usual account, and I haven't set it up on my machine yet. (it seemed so many steps just to do a simple thing)

Comment: You probably *can* do this all on GitHub. Don't: that's a trap. Use command-line Git. It's much harder to get started, but in the end, it's much more *useful*.

Comment: @torek yes... if it is one change, I think it is simple... but now with two changes... I don't know how to do on GitHub `git checkout a3546c` (the original repo's commit ID) and then `git checkout -b my_second_new_branch`, so all the changes in the first PR and second PR lumped together in the second PR... I had to change some files back... it is a mess

Comment: but then again, maybe I can go to `master` or `main`, and then do a new branch, so that branch's change won't go into master automatically, and then for another change, go to `master` again and create another branch base on that

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you put the two commits on the same branch.

You can only have a single PR per source and destination branch pair. If you want to create a second PR, you need to use a different branch name, and then create another PR.

Comment: so can I create a different branch only using GitHub's website?   Or else, I would imagine if they approved the first PR and close it, then I should be able to create a new PR that doesn't go into the first PR

Comment: @StefanieGauss Sure can: https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/creating-and-deleting-branches-within-your-repository

Comment: @StefanieGauss Once the first PR is completed, you could re-use the same branch name again for another PR. Though, personally I typically delete my branches once a PR is completed and just create a new one with a more relevant name for the next change.

Answer (score 0):

> But right now I want to make another change to a different file. So I made the change, and committed, and wanted to create another PR.

You should create a branch for the second change and then create a PR from that branch.

Comment: so can I create a different branch only using GitHub's website?  Or else, I would imagine if they approved the first PR and close it, then I should be able to create a new PR that doesn't go into the first PR

Comment: @StefanieGauss Yes, you can create a branch through the GitHub web UI. See [the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/creating-and-deleting-branches-within-your-repository). P.S. I found this by googling "github branches"